# Smart joins in ArangoDB

Tags: join, arangodb

Smart joins allow documents from related collections to be stored in the same shard, is that also the case for the same collection? I mean: if a document references another document in the same collection, will the smart join feature act the same as if the related document was in another collection?

Answer (score 0):

No, smart joins cannot detect the case of documents in one collection referencing another document in the same collection.
The reason is that there is no way to express these references in ArangoDB at the moment.
If a document from a collection references a document from the same collection, this is an implicit reference, only established (and potentially enforced) by a client application. But for the database this is not a reference but simply data it won't interpret in any special way.

This is different to collections being sharded in the same way as a reference/prototype collection: here an explicit reference is established, by telling the following collections to use a `distributeShardsLike` value that points to the reference/prototype collection.
There is no such thing for individual documents.